# How can I use a 3.5mm Headphone jack as mic only and have a usb headset as output only

Tags: ps4, audio-hardware

So I have a USB headset but the mic on it is broken so I have a mic that I'm trying to use over 3.5mm headphone jack but connecting that to the controller takes over output and input and trying to tell PS4 that the headset on controller is only input and not both, it symmetrically tries to put 1 of them as both I/O. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the system will automatically change the input and output devices whenever they are changed. I experienced this annoyance as well while testing this.

After a little bit of troubleshooting, I was able to get this type of configuration set up. It's a little tricky and you might experience some audio or playback weirdness, but the following are the steps I took to accomplish this:

1. Turn off the USB headset and unplug the 3.5mm headphone jack from your controller

   - Doing this will change all the input and output settings to the systems default
2. Navigate to the system's audio settings

   - Settings, Sound and Screen, Audio Output Settings
3. Uncheck the option to automatically change output settings when new devices are detected

   - This should be the last option in the menu
4. Turn on the USB headset
5. Change the Output device to the USB headset
6. Plug in the 3.5mm headphone jack

   - The system will then automatically change the input device, but not the output device.

By following the steps above, I was able to receive all audio into my USB headset while using the 3.5mm headphones plugged into my controller to chat.